# Distance between upper element and stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I have a `DockPanel` inside the `Grid` to get a layout of the child controls.

However, I need to use a `StackPanel` below this `DockPanel` How do I set the distance between the upper `DockPanel` and the `StackPanel`, since the `StackPanle` always starts from the top and overlays upon the `DockPanel`?

Comment: please put xaml you have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add 2 rows for the Grid.

put DockPanel in first row.
put StackPanel to second row

set StackPanel's margin to be Margin="0,10,0,0"

Note that: Margin="Left,Top,Right, Bottom"

Comment: There are approx. 4 StackPanels for the Window, each StackPanels similarly has 3 or 4 controls each. Would using StackPanels be a better idea or should I follow the above division of Windows into Rows and Columns and then placing each elements into a certain row/column.?

Comment: Can I increase the height of individual rows as well?

Comment: StakPanels VS Grid, I would say that, You should use a Grid if you need things to line up horizontally and vertically. Use a StackPanel to create a row or column of things when those things don't need to line up with anything else.   Yes, you can increase the height of individual rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can set  VerticalAlignment of stackPanel to Bottom.

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"></DockPanel>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></StackPanel>
```

Or crate multiple rows in grid